# Cartopy / Pyproj fail to load _network module // Win 11 // Python 3.10

Tags: python, cartopy, pyproj

I was trying to install cartopy for Python 3.10.11. I followed the instructions at the top of [Christoph Gohlke's site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). I installed the wheels for shapely (Shapely‑1.8.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl), pyproj (pyproj‑3.3.1‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl) and cartopy (Cartopy‑0.20.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl) using pip, version 23.1.2. Furthermore, I have installed the current Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2022.

However, the minimal (non-)working example, that is `import cartopy` in the command line python environment, does give me the following error:

```
File c:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\cartopy\__init__.py:8
      1 # Copyright Cartopy Contributors
      2 #
      3 # This file is part of Cartopy and is released under the LGPL license.
      4 # See COPYING and COPYING.LESSER in the root of the repository for full
      5 # licensing details.
      7 import shapely
----> 8 import pyproj
     10 from ._version import version as __version__  # noqa: F401
     11 import tempfile

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py:49
     32 __all__ = [
     33     "Proj",
     34     "Geod",
   (...)
     45     "show_versions",
...
   (...)
     40         variables.
     41     """

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _network: the specified module could not be found.
```

Other examples, like looking for jupyter kernel folder as mentioned in [a GitHub Issue related to this](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/770#issuecomment-1407508197) didn't work either.

Does anyone know an other workaround for this issue?